# Quotient by action of this matrix group is $S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $M^{2 \times 2}_{\neq 0}$ denote the set of all non-zero $2 \times 2$ real matrices. Note that this set contains non-invertible elements. By an *orthogonal* matrix, let's mean a matrix $A$ such that $AA^\top$ is a non-zero scalar multiple of the identity. Note this is different to the usual definition. Write $\mathrm{Orth}^{2 \times 2}$ for the group of all real orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrices. Let $\mathrm{Orth}^{2 \times 2}$ act on $M^{2 \times 2}_{\neq 0}$ by left-multiplication. I have a hunch that the resulting quotient space is homeomorphic to $S^2$. Is this correct? If so, what's the homeomorphism?

**Remark.** It's explained in the comments that this is the same as trying to find $$\mathbb{RP}^3/O(2).$$ I actually think trying to find $\mathbb{RP}^3/SO(2)$ is the better question, and I think an assumption of orientation-preservingness was implicit in my thinking. However I am interested in both questions.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Orth}^{2\times 2} = \mathbb R^* O(2)$. So you might first mod out the $\mathbb R^*$ action to obtain $\mathbb R\mathbb P^3$ on which you act with the usual orthogonal group $O(2)$ by $A\cdot(u_1:u_2:v_1:v_2)=(u'_1:u'_2:v'_1:v'_2)$ where $u'=Au$, $v'=Av$.

Comment: I see. So is it possible to show that the quotient of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ by $O(2)$ is $S^2$? Or is it a different space?

Comment: Maybe slightly easier is to just restrict your action to $S^3$. I think the resulting space will end up as $\mathbb{RP}^2$, but using $O(2)$ instead of $SO(2)$ makes me question that.

Comment: @SteveD, I hadn't thought of orientation issues. Maybe it's better to stick to $SO(2)$

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer now (I have to teach in a few minutes), but $\mathbb{R}P^3/SO(2) \cong S^2$, while $\mathbb{R}P^3/O(2) \cong \mathbb{R}P^2$.  The short version is that the inclusion map $SO(2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^3$ is surjective on $\pi_1$, so the resulting quotient is simply connected. Further, we have a covering $O(2)/SO(2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^3/SO(2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^3/O(2)$ and since $O(2)/SO(2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, this is a double covering, as expected.

Comment: @JasonDevito: I'm interested to see your answer. The $SO(2)$ case is fairly easy, since the group then is really $\mathbb{R}^+SO(2)$, since negation is already in the orthogonal group. Thus we get a quotient of $S^3$ by an $SO(2)$ action, which is just the Hopf fibration $S^3\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^1$, sending $(z,w)$ to $[z:w]$. But if we use $O(2)$, we have to include complex conjugation as well on the Hopf map. And the quotient of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by conjugation looks to be a disk, not $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @SteveD I think Jason is working with a different - free - action.  $S^3/\text{Pin}(2) \cong \Bbb{RP}^2$, where $\text{Pin}(2)$ is the subgroup of unit quaternions spanned by $S^1$ and $j$. Quotienting both groups by the central element -1, we get $SO(3)$ and $O(2)$, respectively. Without paying too close attention, I think the difference is likely in the identification of the $O(2)$ term: these are supposed to be *oriented* matrices, so really $S(O(2) \times O(1))$. But for the action in the OP, which doesn't have the sign in the bottom right corner, I think you are right.

Comment: But maybe in identifying unit norm matrices with $S^3$ something funky happens.

Comment: Oops, I just assumed the action by $O(2)$ was free (in fact, I just assumed the action by $SO(2)$ is free as well.)  I should have time to start composing an answer in an hour or so.

Answer (score 3):

Steve D's comment is correct.

First, your action is the linear action of $O(2)$ on the sum of 2 of its defining representations, $\Bbb R^2 \oplus \Bbb R^2$.

Now first, observe that if we write $\Bbb R^2 \oplus \Bbb R^2 = \langle 1, i\rangle \oplus \langle j, k\rangle$, then $SO(2)$ acts on each of these in the standard way, and in fact this gives us the inclusion $SO(2) \hookrightarrow S^3$, thinking of $SO(2)$ as the unit complex numbers. The quotient is $S^2$, and the projection map $S^3 \to S^2$ is the Hopf fibration.

What remains is to identify both your $\pm 1$ action on the leftover action of $O(2)/SO(2)$. As Steve D writes in the comments, the $\pm 1$ action on $S^2$ is trivial, as it lives inside $SO(2)$ to begin with.

Write $A$ for the diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$. It will be helpful to write elements of $S^2$ as elements of $\Bbb{CP}^1$. The action given by this matrix on each copy of $\Bbb C$ is complex conjugation; so we are looking at the action $[z:w] \mapsto [\overline z: \overline w]$. This has fixed points equal to $\Bbb{RP}^1$ and swaps the two hemispheres of $S^2$.

Therefore, the quotient of your action is $D^2$. It might be helpful to observe that we may identify this with $[z, 1] \subset \Bbb{CP}^1$ where $\|z\| \leq 1$. Correspondingly, it seems that a near-global slice for your action would be to take upper-triangular matrices with top left term 1 and right column $\|z\| < 1$. ($O(2)$ acts on those with $\|z\| = 1$.)

It is perhaps interesting that this $SO(2)$ action on $S^3$ actually *does* lift to a free action of a $\Bbb Z/2$-extesion of $SO(2)$. The group is $\text{Pin}(2) = S^1 \cup j S^1 \subset S^3$. Instead of acting by complex conjugation on each summand, $j$ swaps the two summands and does a 90 degree rotation (so $j^2 = -1$).

Comment: Great answer.  I was assuming the $O(2)$ action was free because "usually", left multiplication is a free action.  I say usually because if everything is invertible, it is free, which is the case I am used to.  But of course, as your answer indicates, the action is not free.

Comment: @JasonD When I started writing this answer I started with the sentence "Jason DeVito's comment is correct." So I certainly agree it's easy to fool oneself into thinking an action is free! (I also wanted to make an invertibility argument.)